# How to return Object from a Collection?

Tags: java

Given a Collection, how do I return a Object from that Collection knowing the index i?

I can't use the "get" method, so what should I use?

```
public static void remove(Collection coll, Predicate pred) {
    for(int i=0; i<coll.size(); i++) {
        if(pred.test(coll.get(i))) {
            coll.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Error: The method get(int) is undefined for the type Collection

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us why you cannot use the `get()` method, please. First idea: for-each through the collection and return the object that matches your condition. By the way, what is the condition?

Comment: @deHaar added..

Comment: `get(index)` is not defined in `Collection` but only in `List`. Either use `List` or use an iterator to "go" to index `i` and return the element at that index. That's necessary because some collections don't support the notion of an index (e.g. `Set`) but they all support iteration. Note that depending on the type of collection (e.g. when using a set) the iteration order might change so the element at "index" `i` might not always be the same.

Comment: @deHaar well, you can do that but it's easier using an iterator: once the iterator "points" to the element you want to remove you just call `remove()` on the iterator and then you're able to safely able to go on to the next elements.

Comment: @Thomas I used ListIterator<Integer> it = coll.listIterator(); but it says that the method listIterator is undefined for the type Collection

Comment: Well, have a look at the name: `ListIterator` means an iterator on a _list_. `List` is a `Collection` but not all collections are lists (e.g. `Set` is a `Collection` as well but doesn't provide `listIterator()`). You'd need to use `iterator()` instead or switch to `List` only.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) has no such method as `get()`. Use an iterator :

```
    Iterator<Object> iterator = coll.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // Your code here
    }
```

Comment: I typed the iterator as `<Object>`, and you should make your collection as `Collection<Object>` unless you know you are going to get a defined type of collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  public static void remove(Collection coll, Predicate pred) {
            Iterator iterator = coll.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (pred.test(iterator.next())) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
    }
```